# Aftet insert trigger not working when record created by code

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, trigger

I have created a trigger on a custom object. I am creating record of that object from a VF screen. But my trigger does not fire in this case. while creating record manually from standard salesforce layout it gets fired. Can any one tell what is the problem in such case . Refer the trigger code below.

```
trigger PFM_NewTargettrigger on PFM_SalesTarget__c (after insert) {

system.debug(Trigger.new);
List< Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = 
  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  for (PFM_SalesTarget__c tgt : Trigger.new) {    
  account ownerAcc = [SELECT Name, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id = :tgt.PFM_FranchiseAccount__c limit 1][0];

  String EmailAd = [select Email, Id from user where id= :ownerAcc.OwnerId  limit 1][0].Email;
  List<Contact> clist = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE Contact.AccountId = :tgt.PFM_FranchiseAccount__c];
  List<opportunity> lstOpp =[Select Id, Name, Amount, Description, Closedate from opportunity where PFM_SalesTarget__c=:tgt.Id];

  system.debug(clist);
  for(Contact con :clist)
  {          
      if (con.Email != null && con.Name != null) {
           system.debug(con.Email);

      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =  new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();        

      List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
      sendTo.add(con.Email);
      sendTo.add(EmailAd);
      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);       

      mail.setReplyTo(EmailAd);
      mail.setSenderDisplayName('PSL-Franchise Managment System');        

      mail.setSubject('New '+tgt.PFM_Target_Criteria__c+' Sales Target Created');
      String body = 'Hi ' + ownerAcc.Name + ', ';
      body += 'A new '+tgt.PFM_Target_Criteria__c+' Sales target has been created on your name.';          
      mail.setHtmlBody(body);
       mail.setPlainTextBody(body);

      // Step 5. Add your email to the master list
      mails.add(mail);
          system.debug(mail);
    }
  }     
  Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `after insert` trigger will run when an object is inserted by a controller. My guess is that the controller's error reporting is not good so you are failing to see an error from the trigger. Or the trigger is running to completion but is just not sending any email because e.g. no Contacts are returned or the email addresses are not set. Add `System.debug` statements to the trigger and controller to find out what is happening.

Your trigger is coded so that it could easily break e.g. if `PFM_SalesTarget__c .PFM_FranchiseAccount__c` is not set. It is also not coded to handle the case where multiple `PFM_SalesTarget__c` objects are inserted at once, so any bulk loading of that data will produce the wrong results and/or hit a governor limit. I suggest you Google "bulkify trigger" for more information on that.

**PS**

To make sure that your page reports any save errors, make sure that the `save` method results `null` when there are errors so you stay on the same page:

```
public PageReference save() {

    // Do save

    if (ApexPages.getMessages().size() > 0) return null;

    // ...

}
```

and make sure to have an `apex:pageMessages` tag at the top of your page that will output any error messages.

Comment: I am trying to insert a record instead of using controller.save() because controller.save() also not saving my record.. Do you thing this may effect?

Comment: @MahimaGandhe Probably not. See the suggestion I added as a PS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that record was inserted successfully from controller ? I mean by your question it appears that record was inserted but email functionality written in trigger didn't work.
If even record was not inserted try putting debug to know exception.

```
try{
    insert PFMSalesTargetObject ; //place where you are inserting object in controller
   }catch(Exception e){
       System.debug('Exception==='+e);
       ApexPages.addMessages(e);
       }
```

Also make sure your visualforce page has below tag to show errors:

```
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
```

If your record was inserted successfully there could be issue in setting email attributes.Debug your mail object using debug logs. Also use exception handling for send email as well:

```
try{
   Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
   }catch (Exception e){
    System.debug('Email Exception ==='+e);
    }
```

This will allow you to find exact issue blocking this trigger to function properly.